# Design models: search by singleton models in django

Tags: python, django, inheritance, design-patterns, django-models

I have a model `TranslationService`, which has some fields and methods which should be overriden by every new service. I have three services: Google, Azure, Bing, which are the only ones in system (we have only one Google service and one Azure service etc.). I need to perform action like this: `TranslationService.objects.filter(service_name=service_name)`.

But if i make `TranslationService` abstract, i can't iterate over abst class, cause it wasn't created in DB. If I make inheritance I should implement logic of overriding methods in code like model and then create `GoogleService` via console. Is this the only way or I can reduce creating object via console.

**How can I design my models for performing search among translation_services?**

```
class TranslationService(models.Model):
 created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
 updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
 service_name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
 base_url = models.CharField(max_length=255)
 api_version = models.FloatField()

 def get_step_translation(self, pk, lang, lesson):
    pass

 def create_step_translation(self, pk, lang, type):
    pass

class GoogleTranslator(TranslationService):
 base_url = "https://google.com"
 service_name = "Google"
 api_version = 1.5

 def get_step_translation(self, pk, lang, lesson, **kwargs):
  ... some logic
 def create_step_translation(self, pk, lang, type):
  ... some logic
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think model inheritance is the wrong approach here. A model class represents a database table, and your objects all live in the same table, so they should be the same model.

You could just include the logic for each translation method inside if statements, but I understand why you'd want to abstract that out. So how about a separate service class to which you delegate all the operations? You could override `__getattr__` to set up the service and delegate the methods.

```
class GoogleTranslation(object):
    def __init__(self, obj):
        self.obj = obj
    def get_step_translation(self, pk, lang, lesson):
        print('google, {}, {}, {}'.format(pk, lang, lesson))
        ... logic goes here...
    def create_step_translation(self, pk, lang, type):
        ...

class TranslationService(models.Model):
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    service_name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    base_url = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    api_version = models.FloatField()

    services = {
         'google': GoogleTranslation,
         'bing': BingTranslation,
    }

    @property
    def service(self):
        if not hasattr(self, '_service'):
            # create a new Service object and pass it this model instance
            self._service = self.services[self.service_name](self)
        return self._service

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        if name == '_service':
            raise AttributeError   # the service hasn't been instantiated yet
        # delegate all unknown lookups to the service object
        return getattr(self.service, name)
```

Now you can get the Google instance via `gs = TranslationService.objects.get(service_name='google')` and do `gs.get_step_translation(1, '2', '3')` or whatever, and that method call will be delegated to the GoogleTranslation instance.

Comment: When you are calling `get_step_translation`, at first it doesn't find it inside `TranslationService` and calls `__getattr__`, which calls method inside `GoogleTranslation`. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, correct. In fact if there are only those two methods to delegate, this might be a bit overcomplicated; you could just define those two explicitly inside TranslationService and have them call the same method on `self.service`. But if you have lots of methods, this pattern is better.

Comment: The only problem is "access to `TranslationService` fields from GoogleTranslation". Like I can't write `self.base_url` from `GoogleTranslation`  cause of scopes

Comment: You can use `self.obj.base_url`.